# Menubar just shows applications name - OS X

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, menubar

My applications window is generated programmatically. I have a xib file with a menu in it but I really don't know how to link it correct.

The menu bar is empty, except for the bold application name. I tried a few programmatically solutions to link the existing menu or to create and add a completely new menu, but nothing happened.

Does anybody know why this happens? Could it be that there's code in my project which overrides the menu with the empty menu every time?
Is it possible to alter this kind of menu and add menuitems?

Hope you'd help me.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift:

```
let nib = NSNib(nibName: "NameOfXIB", bundle: nil)
nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, topLevelObjects: &array)
```

Objective-C:

```
NSArray *array;
NSNib *nib = [[NSNib alloc] initWithNibNamed:@"MainMenu" bundle:nil];
[nib instantiateWithOwner:self topLevelObjects:&array];
```

In your "array" you have all the top level stuff from XIB.
Hold you objects strongly or they will get released.

Owner is the object where you have IBOUtlets that needs to get linked by instantiation.